# TableView Reusing the Same Cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableview, I am receiving a strange error. I have an array of dictionaries named _cellTextArray, and that dictionary contains the keys "textLabel", "detailTextLabel" and "cornerLabel". However I created three UILabel's which are added to the contentView of the cell and their text is set to their corresponding name in the dictionary. My problem is that the textLabels are only retrieving the first 5 objects in the dictionary, and using them for every cell rather than retrieving the object at the index of the cell in the dictionary.

Please could you tell me what I am doing wrong. I have combed through the code a few times, NSLog'ing the dictionaryValues for each indexPath, and they are all correct.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    CheckBox *btn = (CheckBox *)[_checkboxArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
        //I added this code:
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3; // 0 means no max.


        UIImageView* img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient7.png"]] autorelease];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];

        UILabel *lab = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 18, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-15, 22)] autorelease];
        [lab setText:[[_cellTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"textLabel"]];
        [lab setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lab setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [lab setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [lab setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];

        UILabel *dlabl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 54, cell.contentView.frame.size.width- 1, 22)] autorelease];
        [dlabl setText:[[_cellTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"detailTextLabel"]];
        [dlabl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.80 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [dlabl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       // [dlabl setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [dlabl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [dlabl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[lab font].pointSize - 3]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dlabl];

        UILabel *cornerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 40, 19, 40, 20)] autorelease];
        [cornerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        //[cornerLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        [cornerLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [cornerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cornerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cornerLabel];
        [cornerLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [cornerLabel setText:[[_cellTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cornerLabel"]];

        // Adds image to cell
      //  UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 140, 50)] autorelease];
     //   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[_cellTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
     //   [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];            
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **Listing 5-3** on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) (iOS Table View Programming Guide) to see how it is done properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the data when there are no reusable cells. Once they are there, the table view won't ask for a new cell. So your data isn't being set. You are plainly returning the reused cell. You should set all the static properties (which don't depend on the row data) within that cell and bring all assignments outside the if statement. In this case, they seem to be the `setText:` statements of the three labels.